# ошибка Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function fun1() {
 var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex;
 var options= document.getElementById('mySelect').options;
 alert("Выбрана опция" +options[sel].text);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <select name="" id="mySelect" onchange="fun1()">
  <option value="">apple</option>
  <option value="">orange</option>
  <option value="">pinapple</option>
  <option value="">banana</option>
 </select>


 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Не понимаю, что не так

Comment: У вас рабочий код.

Comment: странно, у меня в Chrome выдает ошибку

Comment: Ваш код работает, к тому же вы не используете `onСlick`, на который ссылается ошибка.

Comment: В заголовке у вас ошибка `Cannot set property onclick of null`, а код вы добавили с `onchange`. Думаю, ошибка в том, какой код вы добавили в вопрос.

Comment: нет, ошибку в браузере выдает именно этот

Comment: Тем не менее этот код абсолютно рабочий.

Comment: Все работает, проверено. Может, ошибку выдает другой кусок кода на вашей странице?